# SQL: How to return values for certain data with at least 2 records on the same date

Tags: sql

I have a database with OrderID and TradeID and Date.

Where 1 order can be completed by multiple trades on multiple dates. I would like to select just the OrderIDs that have at least 2 trades on 1 day.

I already have list of OrderIds with multiple trades (In fact, the table has Filled price too and whole task is to Pick orders with Multiple trades on 1 day with different filled price, but I think I managed to pick orders with multiple trades with different prices via:

```
SELECT OrderID ...
FROM ORDERTABLE
WHERE ORDERID IN (
  SELECT OrderID
  FROM ORDERTABLE
  GROUP BY ORDERID
  HAVING COUNT(OrderID) > 1 AND COUNT(Distinct Price) > 1
)
```

Can you suggest, how to amend the query to select only orders with more trades (If orders has more trades, the OrderID is in database several times) where at least 2 are on the same day AND have different price at the same time.

Examples:

OrderId 1 has 2 trades on 1.1.1111 with price per trade 10 and 11. So this would be shown.

OrderID 2 has 2 trades on 1.1.1111 with price per trade 10 and 10. So this would NOT be shown.

OrderID 3 has 3 trades on 2x on 1.1.1111 and 1x on 2.1.1111 with price of 10 for both trades on 1.1.1111 and price of 11 on 2.1.1111. This would NOT be shown.

Comment: A proper [mcve] would make this clearer. Also add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: You are saying "Date" in most places, but here you say "Time" - "AND have different price at the same time" . Does that field have any time precision, if so is it the only the date that matters? Or is everything just date?

Comment: I think you just have to add AND COUNT(Distinct trunc(date)) = 1 right after HAVING COUNT(OrderID) > 1 AND COUNT(Distinct Price) > 1 condition

Comment: @gogocho, note that trunc is product specific, and the the dbms unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Group by add OrderID,TradeDate
In having condition check count(distinct price)>1

Try this one

```
Declare @ORDERTABLE as table
(TradeID int identity(1,1),
OrderID int,
price decimal(18,4),
TradeDate date)

insert into @ORDERTABLE(OrderID,price,TradeDate)
values(1,10,'2023-12-21')

insert into @ORDERTABLE(OrderID,price,TradeDate)
values(1,12,'2023-12-21')

insert into @ORDERTABLE(OrderID,price,TradeDate)
values(2,12,'2023-12-21')

insert into @ORDERTABLE(OrderID,price,TradeDate)
values(2,12,'2023-12-21')

select OrderID,TradeDate,count(distinct price) as cnt 
from @ORDERTABLE
group by  OrderID,TradeDate
having count(distinct price)>1
```

Comment: an **answer** should not contain: "Try this one" .... 